Spring's beanNameGenerator in Azure Function
Whilst creating Java Azure Functions utilizing Spring boot, I want to use FullyQualifiedAnnotationBeanNameGenerator in order to use same class names for Components in different packages (e.g.: different implementations of an interface).
This is how I'm trying to achieve this:
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(
    basePackages = "com.company",
    nameGenerator = FullyQualifiedAnnotationBeanNameGenerator.class)
public class Application {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(Config.class, args);
  }
}

However, I'm getting this exception when one of the functions (Http Triggered) is called:
Exception: ConflictingBeanDefinitionException: Annotation-specified bean name 'serviceImpl' for bean class [com.company.pkg.service.ServiceImpl] conflicts with existing, non-compatible bean definition of same name and class [com.company.otherpkg.service.ServiceImpl]
Stack: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to initialize
at org.springframework.cloud.function.adapter.azure.AzureFunctionInstanceInjector.getInstance(AzureFunctionInstanceInjector.java:80)
at com.microsoft.azure.functions.worker.binding.ExecutionContextDataSource.getFunctionInstance(ExecutionContextDataSource.java:103)
at com.microsoft.azure.functions.worker.broker.JavaMethodInvokeInfo.invoke(JavaMethodInvokeInfo.java:20)
at com.microsoft.azure.functions.worker.broker.EnhancedJavaMethodExecutorImpl.execute(EnhancedJavaMethodExecutorImpl.java:22)
at com.microsoft.azure.functions.worker.chain.FunctionExecutionMiddleware.invoke(FunctionExecutionMiddleware.java:19)
at com.microsoft.azure.functions.worker.chain.InvocationChain.doNext(InvocationChain.java:21)
at com.microsoft.azure.functions.worker.broker.JavaFunctionBroker.invokeMethod(JavaFunctionBroker.java:125)
at com.microsoft.azure.functions.worker.handler.InvocationRequestHandler.execute(InvocationRequestHandler.java:34)
at com.microsoft.azure.functions.worker.handler.InvocationRequestHandler.execute(InvocationRequestHandler.java:10)
at com.microsoft.azure.functions.worker.handler.MessageHandler.handle(MessageHandler.java:44)
at com.microsoft.azure.functions.worker.JavaWorkerClient$StreamingMessagePeer.lambda$onNext$0(JavaWorkerClient.java:94)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:539)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840)

In this case, com.company.pkg.service.ServiceImpl and com.company.otherpkg.service.ServiceImpl are the 2 implementations of an interface, each is annotated with a unique Qualifier, and each is annotated as Component.
The function that's being called is injected with the interface (Service<TypeIn, TypeOut>) using a Qualifier.
@Component
public class MyHandler implements HttpHandler {
  private final Service<TypeIn, TypeOut> service;

  @Autowired
  public MyHandler(
      @Qualifier("myUniqueQualifier")
          Service<TypeIn, TypeOut> service) {
            this.service = service;
  }
}

So, given fully qualified bean names, I was hoping components with the same name (but in different packages) can co-exist.

The trouble is that the "nameGenerator" setting isn't propagated through Spring's cloud adapter for Azure. In other words, the default name generator (`AnnotationBeanNameGenerator`) is used instead.
Looking at the code, this makes sense. AzureFunctionInstanceInjector class creates its own SpringApplication.
How to get this internally created SpringApplication use the nameGenerator settings (e.g.: an environment variable)?

Upon debugging the code, I can see that fully qualified bean names are indeed generated.
I'm wondering then if someone could explain what this error really means and why it's happening:
Annotation-specified bean name conflicts with existing, non-compatible bean definition of same name and class.

Downvote with no explanation isn't helpful. If something needs to change, please elaborate what it is.

For anyone who lands here and has the same problem.
To resolve this, I moved the Application class to a sub-package and excluded that package from "Component Scan".
package com.company.newpkg;

@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(
    basePackages = "com.company",
    nameGenerator = FullyQualifiedAnnotationBeanNameGenerator.class,
    excludeFilters =
        @ComponentScan.Filter(
            type = FilterType.REGEX,
            pattern = "com\\.company\\.newpkg\\..*")))
public class Application {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(Config.class, args);
  }
}

Why this worked?
SpringBootApplication interface also uses a @ComponentScan annotation which registers components using the default name generator (class name only). This resulted in components being registered twice: once with a default name and another with fully-qualified name.
